# How can I make the goaccess package available in Lucid (10.04)?

Tags: apt, package-management

GoAccess is an open source real-time web log analyzer and interactive viewer that runs in a terminal in *nix systems. For some reason, it appears that [it is only available in the repos for 12.04 and later.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=goaccess) I would like to make this available as a package in 10.04, but I do not know how to go about doing that.

Is there a good reason why this package is not available for Lucid? [The server version should be supported going into 2015.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) I would prefer to remain on Lucid for a while longer. I am also trying to find a solution that avoids downloading and installing programs and scripts in an ad hoc manner. Can anyone shed some light on this, or point me in the right direction to start working toward a solution?

Comment: The good reason you are looking for may be that the package wasn't packaged upon release of 10.04 and packages will not be added to the repository after release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the .deb file for [32-bit](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/goaccess/goaccess_0.4.2-2_i386.deb) or [64-bit](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/goaccess/goaccess_0.4.2-2_amd64.deb). Install it with `dpkg -i path/to/download.deb` It may (probably) complain that some dependencies are missing, if so, install them. If you need a higher version, look around [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com) for the one in precise fitting your needs.

Comment: I have begun the process which you described, however, `goaccess` depends on `libtinfo5`, which in turn, depends on `multiarch-support`. When I went to download `multiarch-support`, the site had a strong suggestion not to do what I was doing. Is this something I should be concerned about? http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/multiarch-support/download

Comment: It is only saying that because it is better to use apt-get instead of raw dpkg. This won't work in your case.

Comment: I did it, and it worked. Any idea why this isn't in the Lucid repos if it works this way? Seems like it could just as easily be in the Lucid repository.

Comment: To say the truth, I have no idea. It might be because Canonical hasn't tested GoAccess under Lucid.

Answer (score 1):

You may use GoAccess official Debian/Ubuntu's repository, installs well on 10.04.

http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/download#debian